# Instancia de determinado tipo não pode ser rastreada porque outra instância com o mesmo valor-chave para {'ID'} já está sendo rastreada

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Estou tentando atualizar uma entidade minha no banco mas sem sucesso, visualizei outros posts do assunto, e a solução deles parece não estar servindo para mim.

Estou usando o Entity Framework Core Versão 5.0.9

Na minha função do repositório

```
public void Editar(Pessoa obj)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;

            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Ja tentei usar `_context.Attach(obj);` mas estoura o erro nessa mesma linha de codigo

Ja tentei usar `_context.Update(obj);` mas tambem estoura o mesmo erro

Ja tentei usar `_context.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Detached;`, junto com o `_context.SaveChanges();`, mas meu objeto no banco não é alterado

Nome do erro

**The instance of entity type 'Pessoa' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'CodigoCliente'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.**

Os metodos de Busca, Deletar e Criar funcionam normalmente

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Pessoa> Pessoa { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Licenca> Licenca { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //modelBuilder.Entity<PessoaConfig>();
        //modelBuilder.Entity<LicencaConfig>();

        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new PessoaConfig());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new LicencaConfig());


        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}


public class PessoaConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Pessoa>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Pessoa> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Cliente");

        builder.HasKey(x => x.CodigoCliente);

        builder.Property(x => x.CodigoCliente).HasColumnName("cd_cliente");
        builder.Property(x => x.TipoPessoa).HasColumnName("tp_pessoa");
        builder.Property(x => x.Advogado).HasColumnName("fl_advogado");
        builder.Property(x => x.Captador).HasColumnName("fl_captador");
        builder.Property(x => x.Cobrador).HasColumnName("fl_cobrador");
        builder.Property(x => x.Cliente).HasColumnName("fl_cliente");
        builder.Property(x => x.Fornecedor).HasColumnName("fl_fornecedor");
        builder.Property(x => x.Devedor).HasColumnName("fl_devedor");
        builder.Property(x => x.Nome).HasColumnName("no_cliente");
        builder.Property(x => x.InscricaoEstadual).HasColumnName("nr_ie");
        builder.Property(x => x.InscricaoMunicipal).HasColumnName("nr_im");
        builder.Property(x => x.Rg).HasColumnName("nr_ci");
        builder.Property(x => x.Login).HasColumnName("cd_usuario");
        builder.Property(x => x.TipoAdvogado).HasColumnName("tp_advogado");
        builder.Property(x => x.Observacao).HasColumnName("de_observacao");
        builder.Property(x => x.GrupoSeguranca).HasColumnName("cd_grupo");
        builder.Property(x => x.Atividade).HasColumnName("cd_atividade");
        builder.Property(x => x.Contato).HasColumnName("fl_contato");
        builder.Property(x => x.Oficial).HasColumnName("fl_oficiais");
        builder.Property(x => x.Segurado).HasColumnName("fl_segurados");
        builder.Property(x => x.GrupoCliente).HasColumnName("cd_grupo_cliente");
        builder.Property(x => x.Autor).HasColumnName("fl_autor");
        builder.Property(x => x.Reu).HasColumnName("fl_reu");
        builder.Property(x => x.CodigoAlteracao).HasColumnName("cd_alteracao");
        builder.Property(x => x.DataAlteracao).HasColumnName("dt_alteracao");
        builder.Property(x => x.CodigoCriacao).HasColumnName("cd_criacao");
        builder.Property(x => x.DataCriacao).HasColumnName("dt_criacao");
        builder.Property(x => x.Filial).HasColumnName("cd_filial_cliente");
        builder.Property(x => x.Inativo).HasColumnName("fl_inativo");
        builder.Property(x => x.Localizador).HasColumnName("fl_localizador");
        builder.Property(x => x.Usuario).HasColumnName("fl_usuario");
        builder.Property(x => x.Filiais).HasColumnName("cd_filialss");
        builder.Property(x => x.Nascimento).HasColumnName("dt_nascimento");
        builder.Property(x => x.Setor).HasColumnName("cd_setor");
        builder.Property(x => x.Amigavel).HasColumnName("fl_amigavel");
        builder.Property(x => x.Juridico).HasColumnName("fl_juridico");
        builder.Property(x => x.Horario).HasColumnName("cd_horario");
        builder.Property(x => x.Admissao).HasColumnName("dt_admissao");
        builder.Property(x => x.Rescisao).HasColumnName("dt_rescisao");
        builder.Property(x => x.Banco).HasColumnName("cd_banco");
        builder.Property(x => x.Agencia).HasColumnName("nr_agencia");
        builder.Property(x => x.Conta).HasColumnName("nr_conta");
        builder.Property(x => x.Cartorio).HasColumnName("fl_cartorio");
        builder.Property(x => x.Admissao2).HasColumnName("dt_admissao2");
        builder.Property(x => x.Rescisao2).HasColumnName("dt_rescisao2");
        builder.Property(x => x.GrupoCobranca).HasColumnName("cd_grupo_cobranca");
        builder.Property(x => x.DigitoConta).HasColumnName("cd_dv");
        builder.Property(x => x.Cpf).HasColumnName("nr_cpf");
        builder.Property(x => x.Cnpj).HasColumnName("nr_cgc");
        builder.Property(x => x.ArquivoMorto).HasColumnName("de_morto");
        builder.Property(x => x.Cargo).HasColumnName("cd_cargo");
        builder.Property(x => x.Ramal).HasColumnName("nr_ramal_cob");
        builder.Property(x => x.Empresa).HasColumnName("cd_empresa");
        builder.Property(x => x.Email).HasColumnName("de_mail");
        builder.Property(x => x.ValidaHorario).HasColumnName("fl_valida_horario");
        builder.Property(x => x.PosJuridico).HasColumnName("fl_pos_juridico");
        builder.Property(x => x.Oab).HasColumnName("nr_inscricao_oab");
        builder.Property(x => x.CarteiraFoco).HasColumnName("fl_foco");
        builder.Property(x => x.DigitoAgencia).HasColumnName("cd_dv_agencia");
        builder.Property(x => x.OpVar).HasColumnName("cd_op_var");
        builder.Property(x => x.Pis).HasColumnName("nr_pis");
        builder.Property(x => x.UtilizaSoftPhone).HasColumnName("fl_discador");
        builder.Property(x => x.CarteiraWo).HasColumnName("fl_wo");
        builder.Property(x => x.Senha).HasColumnName("id_password");
        builder.Property(x => x.TipoCentral).HasColumnName("fl_tipo_central");
        builder.Property(x => x.DiscagemManual).HasColumnName("fl_manual");
        builder.Property(x => x.CentralAlternativa).HasColumnName("fl_alternativa");
        builder.Property(x => x.Receptivo).HasColumnName("fl_receptivo");
        builder.Property(x => x.MetaDiscador).HasColumnName("fl_meta_discador");
        builder.Property(x => x.SapClienteNcNds).HasColumnName("cd_cliente_sap_nc");
        builder.Property(x => x.SapClienteNrp).HasColumnName("cd_cliente_sap_nrp");
        builder.Property(x => x.SapFornecedorNds).HasColumnName("cd_cliente_sap");
        builder.Property(x => x.EmailFuncional).HasColumnName("cd_contato_se");
        builder.Property(x => x.TipoUsuario).HasColumnName("fl_tipo_usuario");
        builder.Property(x => x.Fiador).HasColumnName("fl_fiador");
        builder.Property(x => x.SegurancaGrupoCobranca).HasColumnName("cd_seg_grupo_cobranca");
    }
```

Se precisar de mais informações para descobrir o erro pode pedir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente inserir o seguinte no construtor do seu contexto:

```
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
            ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
            ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Ari, poderia dar uma breve explicação do que significa essas mudanças que você sugeriu ? e no que pode impactar no meu sistema

Comment: A mesma solução pode ser implementada nas funções do seu repositório

Answer (score 0):

Eu modificaria seu método de edição para Assíncrono primeiramente e faria alguns testes:

```
public async Task Editar(Pessoa p)
{
    //Faria o Track da entidade a partir de uma busca
    var pessoa = await _context.Pessoa.FindAsync(p.Id);
    
    //Faria a alterações
    pessoa.Nome = "Fulano";
    _context.Pessoa.Update(pessoa);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Faz o teste e ve o que da.

**Edit 1:**

Com base na sua resposta vamos tentar assim:

Sua Controller que recebe o JSON e que tem o repositório injetado com método de atualizar:

```
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update(Guid id, [FromBody] PessoaDTO pessoaDTO)
    {
        try
        {               
            if (id == Guid.Empty || authorDTO == null || id != authorDTO.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            var pessoa = _mapper.Map<Pessoa>(pessoaDTO);
            var isSuccess = await _pessoaRepository.Update(pessoa);
            if (!isSuccess)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            return NoContent();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

Seu repositorio por sua vez utilizando o context para executar as mudanças:

```
    public async Task<bool> Update(Pessoa entity)
    {
        _context.Pessoas.Update(entity);
        return await Save();
    }
```

Comment: Da maneira que você sugeriu funciona, mas da maneira que eu estou tentando fazer é diferente, vou te explicar as etapas até chegar ao método do repositório... 1 - Recebo esses dados via Json. 2 - Uso o AutoMapper para mapear todas as propriedades para a classe Pessoa. 3 - Busco por ID o que eu recebi via JSON. e guardo numa variável  4 - Atribuo o objeto mapeado para essa variável. 5 - Envido todo esse objeto modificado para o metodo de Editar do Repositorio.... Seguindo esse procedimento é possível fazer? pois da maneira que você indicou ficara difícil dar escalabilidade a isso.

Comment: Tenta o edit que fiz

Answer (score 0):

Tracking (Rastreio) acontece sempre que você faz uma consulta ao banco de dados por uma ou mais entidades. O tracking ajuda o Entity framework a perceber a mudança de um objeto antes dele ir para o banco de dados. Ele dispara um `OnChangeNotification` e guarda isso nas propriedades do Contexto do EF. [Você pode ver o detalhamento desse comportamento aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/change-tracking/change-detection).

O Tracking tem o sua desvantagem, ele atinge tambem diretamente a peformance do seu código, pois o EF terá que ficar observando as modificações das propriedades dos objetos até que ele seja salvo no DB. Porém sem ele, você perderá a grande vantagem do EF de executar todas as alterações de um DBContexto em uma unica transação.

É posivel desativar o tracker diretamente no DBContext, porém eu não recomendo se a sua aplicação faz muitas alterações no banco de dados.

**Minha recomendação**: Quando fizer uma query usando EF, considere se você vai precisar fazer o tracker de toda modificação do objeto antes de ir pro banco de dados. A grande maioria das vezes que você usar `.ToList()` e retornar o objeto por uma API por exemplo, você não precisará usar os trackers do EF, nesse caso, use `[YourEFQuery].AsNoTracking().ToList()` (se você não tiver modificado o tracker no DBContexto).

No Geral, quando você recebe os dados usando um `.Find()` baseado em um `ID` isso irá vir com o tracker habilitado, e faz sentido que seja assim, afinal você está querendo uma unica entidade para fazer modificações.